# Is PHP 5.4 compatible with PHP 4.4.2?

Tags: php, iis-6

I was recently asked about a legacy application that is running on PHP 4.4.2 on IIS 6.0. We were informed that this version of PHP is out of date and contains [security vulnerabilities](http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-74/product_id-128/version_id-30105/opec-1/PHP-PHP-4.4.2.html%5D%5Bsecurity%20vulnerabilities)

*I personally, have **zero** experience with PHP.*

It has been suggested that we upgrade PHP to a later version. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), the latest stable version is 5.4. Is version 5.4 backward compatible with 4.4.2?

I assume that there is an installer for PHP 5.4 that we could run that would install the new version of PHP. Would that work safely and the legacy application would still run fine?

Are there any breaking changes in newer versions of PHP that might make upgrading the legacy PHP application risky?

Comment: Have you tried to investigate? http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.incompatible.php

Comment: Is this code running on stone tablets? PHP 4 support ended over 5 years ago, it's practically prehistoric.

Comment: Upgrading PHP is not going to be your problem.  You problem comes in if you have code that isn't compatible with the new version.  These links to the list of backwards incompatibilities are valuable, but either you're going to have to learn some PHP or get the assistance of someone familiar with the language to help you fix any broken code.

Comment: Install 5.4, move the code over, and then test it. I am almost certain you will run into some problems, but you have to actually put some effort into it, to see if the code will fly or not.

Comment: Another potential reference for you (or your PHP developer): [Upgrading to PHP5](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596006365.do) from O'Reiley Media. I haven't used this book myself, but it's a potential resource for you.

Comment: @Barmar: There are no PHP developers in this organisation, hence it hasn't been maintained and no one in the IT department knows anything about how it works, what it does, etc.

Comment: the simple answer would be not completely ... rather you can not say that  5.3 is compatible with 5.4 .. because its not completely

Comment: "I personally, have zero experience with PHP." when i lack a skill, or the time, i hire someone.

Comment: @Dagon - That's what I would do too, if it were my call to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this, check for any `deprecated` code (especially `preg` VS `ereg` ) -

http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.incompatible.php

Look for the `general differences` -

http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.general.php#faq.general.differences-45

Check about the `migration` -

http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.migration5.php

**EDIT** -

One more general link, may be helpful at times  -
[Check Change Logs](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php)